# PostgreSQL | Can't drop tables from shell script using psql

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql, shell, psql

I am trying to drop all the tables from a database and for which I am executing this command `DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;` and same can be achieved from psql in following way `psql postgresql://$db_username:$db_password@localhost/$db -c "DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;"` which is working as expected.

When I try to execute the same command from shell script, it fails to drop the tables and I get this output ***DROP SCHEMA***. Following is the shell script which is not working.

```
drop_tables(){
  echo "-------DELETING ALL TABLES FROM $db_name--------"
  psql postgresql://$db_username:$db_password@localhost/$db -c "DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;"
  echo "-------ALL TABLES DROPPED SUCCESSFULLY!--------"
}
```

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: where do you initialize the variables?

Comment: You might want to add an "Are you sure? " prompt in there.

Comment: @glennjackman variables are declared right above the function. Why do I need a prompt?

Comment: Deleting all tables? Seems like something you don't want to call by accident. Do as you will though. And using global variables is bad practice: you should pass them to the function as parameters, as you would in any other structured program.

Comment: @Cyrus Thank you for your suggestion of debugging. glennjackman Thank you for your suggestion for variables. Instead of $db it was supposed to be $db_name.

Comment: On a side note, `drop schema` and `drop table` is not the same thing. Confusing the two will eventually lead to some issues (sequence, functions, new table creation etc)

Comment: @JGH is there any other way to drop all the tables apart from this?

Comment: You can try something like `SELECT format('DROP TABLE public.%I', tablename)
FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables
WHERE schemaname='public';\gexec`  It will first select the tablename, then call the drop command on each found name